# Is it possible to create a function with an array as one parameter and a second parameter to hold the size of parameter 1 - the array?

Tags: c, arrays, function

"The first parameter is an array of ints and the second is an int, the number of elements in the array. The function does not return a value."

The function is not meant to return anything, so I have return void. I can create the array just fine but I'm unsure if I can create an integer param that directly influences the size of the array of the first parameter.

```
void printArray(int x[], int arrayCount);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you haven't tried it. Yes, it is valid code and that is indeed the right way.

Comment: This is perfectly valid code. You could wrap the two parameters inside a struct to pass them in unison like this `typedef struct { int* array; size_t size; } my_int_array;`.

Comment: you must assume the size argument matches the actual size of the array. there's no way to enforce it at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid code

`void printArray(int x[], int arrayCount);`

even though the second parameter would be better with type `size_t` to hold the number of the first parameter (array) elements.

Comment: What would the size_t code look like? int size_t(arrayCount)?

Comment: size_t is a type alias for unsigned 64 bit integer. size_t is the correct type to use when referring to sizes for arrays because it supports all of the possible values you would need.

Comment: @ChrisRollins not necessarily 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern in C.  A function that takes a an array (or pointer) along with a "size" parameter.

In your implementation of `printArray`, you don't actually create the array, it's already passed to you:

And you can test your code as follows

```
 void printArray(int x[], int arrayCount)
 {
      // your code goes here
 }


 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
      int testArray1[] = {8,6,7,5,3,0,9};
      int count1 = sizeof(testArray1) / sizeof(testArray1[0]);  // 7

      printArray(testArray1, count1);

      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `size_t arrayCount` ?

Comment: As I'm two months into C, what would size_t arrayCount mean?

Comment: @artm - correct. It's better to be size_t.  I was going off what the OP posted since that was what he posted. I was assuming that's how his instructor wanted him to code it.

Comment: `size_t` is just another way of saying `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`.  Since array lengths can't be negative, size_t is the type returned by the `sizeof` operator.  It's always unsigned.

Comment: Instead of declaring `arrayCount` and `count1` above as type `int`, you'd declare them all as `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create a function with an array as one parameter and a second parameter to hold the size of parameter 1 - the array?

Yes and no.

Yes, the below code is OK.  But no,  `x` is *not* an array. Function parameters cannot be an *array* in C - even if `int x[]` looks like one.   In the case of function parameters, `int x[]` is the same as a `int *x`.  `x` is a *pointer* - a pointer to `int`.

```
void printArray(int x[], int arrayCount);
```

This is not a problem in usage.  Consider the below.  In many cases, an array is converted to the address of the first element of the array.  Here, `fred` is converted `&fred[0]` as the first argument to `printArray()`.

```
int fred[42];
printArray(fred, 42);
```

A sample  implementation of `printArray()` prints the size of paramter `x`.  Note it is the size of a *pointer*.

```
void printArray(int x[], int arrayCount) {
  printf("Size of x %zu\n", sizeof x);
}
```